# Is there any free tool for profiler of MYSQL database?

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Is there any free tool for profiler of MYSQL database?

I want to capture the SQL statement from application.
and want to tune it for performenencae.

Can any one suggest?

Thanks,
Paresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and the [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html)

Edit: The minimum supported MySQL version is 5.0.37. You can download 5.1.45 directly from [mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/).

Comment: Can you send me the latest freeware version of MYSQL which have profiling?